# memset with math class macros

Tags: c, memset, math.h, string.h

I am trying to use memset with INFINITY or NAN present in C header file <math.h>
My code is:

```
double *dist;
dist = (double *)malloc(7*sizeof(double));
memset(dist, INFINITY, 7*sizeof(dist[0]));
```

However, on execution it gives me the following errors:

```
main.c:10:18: warning: overflow in conversion from ‘float’ to ‘int’ changes value from ‘+Inff’ to ‘2147483647’ [-Woverflow]
   11 |     memset(dist, INFINITY, 7*sizeof(dist[0]));
```

But I know INFINITY and NAN is represented using float. So why is it giving me an error?
I even tried by using float instead of double but same issue. But, with any other floating point values it is working perfectly.
Please help.

P.S.: It works perfectly fine if I use a loop instead of memset.

Edit: Is there any other way of doing this by avoiding the loop?

Comment: `memset()` sets each byte of the destination to the specified value. You can't use it with values larger than a byte. Just write an ordinary `for` loop.

Comment: If all else fails, [read the instructions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset).

Comment: But then @Barmar how is it possible with other large double values or with loops? Can you please explain?

Comment: What's `d`? That seems to be missing a definition

Comment: @SuryaMajumder Because most other floating point values can be converted to `int`. It still won't do what you want.

Comment: `INFINITY` is a macro based on a `float` expression, per the ISO C standard. Typically, `float` is implemented via the `binary32` type of the IEEE-754 standard (i.e. 4 bytes). The second argument to `memset` is an `int`, and an `unsigned char` typecast is applied to it, meaning it is a effectively a 1 byte argument. Unsurprisingly, this results in a *warning*, because the effect of what is being done here is unlikely to be what the programmer intended. There is no error message shown. `memset` *cannot* be used to initialize `float` data to `INFINITY`.

Comment: For instance, `123.0` will be converted to the integer `123` without generating an error. But setting each byte of a float to `123` will not initialize the float to `123.0`.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in other answers, the `memset` is not going to work because it fills the data with a *single byte* pattern. In the single precision floating point standard 754, the "infinity" is be encoded as `00 00 80 7f` bytes (assuming little endian). Therefore it is not possible to use `memset` for desired initialization. Frankly, it's difficult to use this function for initialization with anything other than zeros or all-one bits.

However, if you use GCC, CLANG or ICC then there is an extensions allowing specify ranges in designated initializers:

```
float arr[] = { [0 ... 6] = INFINITY };
```

The either use `arr` as `dist` or copy it with `memcpy`.

```
memcpy(dist, arr, sizeof arr);
```

The compiler may be smart enough to optimize this operation.

The operation can be "one-lined" with a help of compound initializer.

```
memcpy(dist, (float[]){ [0 ... 6] = INFINITY }, 7 * sizeof *dist);
```

Comment: I believe the loop method is more efficient, because instead of having a separate object storing the repeated value, you only store the value once in the binary

Comment: @user16217248, probably loop is faster or the same. However OP was asking about non-loop solution

Answer (score 2):

`memset` sets each byte to a given byte value. A `double` is bigger than a byte so one cannot use `memset` to set a `double` buffer to `INFINITY`. The best way to accomplish this is via a loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
    dist[i] = INFINITY;
```